# Displacement Mapping opengl-es

Tags: opengl, 3d, iphone, ios, opengl-es

I need to do an application similar to this [Morfo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/morfo/id418900007?mt=8). And I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344430/opengles-display-human-face-in-iphone) where the answer states the solution is "[Displacement Mapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Displacement)" . And I googled this to do it in opengles. I couldnt get how to start and implement this in opengles. Can someone give me some starter on this?

Comment: I don't think displacement mapping is the easiest solution, it makes displacement in directions other than the normal direction very hard. I would suggest that you use "morph targets" (also known as "blend shapes" and many other names). This would bend your definition of "one model" but using displacement mapping seems a lot more complicated to me. Also, besides blend-shapes there's various deformer methods you could use for basic scaling/stretching. But generally your problem seems to be more that the texture projection is wrong, so I'd say fix your texture projection first.

Comment: Well, didn't see how ancient this question was, SO sorting is really weird.